# How to properly include self built shared Library in Project

Tags: pycharm, python-c-api

I have a self built shared Library that I want to include in my project.
The Library is working and my program can run, but PyCharm is complaining
that it can not find my module. Here is a minimal example:

```c
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static PyObject * print(PyObject *self, PyObject *noargs) {
   // printf() displays the string inside quotation
   printf("Hello, World!");

   return Py_None;
}

static PyMethodDef myLibMethods[] = {
    {"print",  print, METH_NOARGS,
     "Execute a shell command."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};

static struct PyModuleDef myLibmodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "cmcts",   /* name of module */
    NULL, /* module documentation, may be NULL */
    -1,       /* size of per-interpreter state of the module, or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables. */
    myLibMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_myLib(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&myLibmodule);
}
```

and the setup.py.

```python
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('myLib', sources=['test.c'])

setup(name='PackageName',
      version='1.0',
      description='This is a demo package',
      ext_modules=[module1])
```

I run `python setup.py build` which works, but when I use it PyCharm can't find the module although it can execute it.

[image]

For now I just copied the .so into the same folder.

[image]

This is very likely not the way you are supposed to do it. Which brings me to my 2 questions.

1. How can I get PyCharm to find my module?
   and more importantly:
2. How do I setup my Project for C_extensions?

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom paths this way (which is very convoluted imo).

- Go to File->Settings->project Interpreter
- In the Project-Interpreter field, click the down facing arrow and select "show All"
- In the Menu that pops up, highlight your interpreter and then in the top-left is a toolbar, and on the right of it is the button "Show interpreter paths". Click it.
- Click the plus symbol to add your path

As far as your second question, it looks like you need CLion with a Python extension to get the static analyzer to work correctly.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. Regarding 1) Why is it not enough to mark the directory as a src directory? Regarding 2) That is not exactly what I meant. What I meant is: How do I structure my project correctly? Where do I put the .c files? How do I build it (setup.py)? I mean. Since C is platform dependent my project including the C-Extension should be built differently right if I would install it using pip?

Comment: Regarding 1) I tried adding the path and afterwards used invalidate caches. PyCharm still won't recognise my .so as a Python module.